# What additional steps do I need to take to change a title of a question back to the original title?

Tags: discussion, editing, specific-question

I wrote a question and a day later noticed the title had been edited by another user.

The original title: When writing the net ionic equation, if one of the products ionizes, what is the most appropriate way to account for this in the answer?

Edited to: [Writing the net ionic equation](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141042)

Which is clearly not represented as the well thought out question I had first presented, and more than anything qualifies as a statement as opposed to a question.

I would like to change the title of my question back, through the appropriate channels in hopes that anyone else who has the same question will be able to receive an answer. Ideally, I hope another user would be able to confirm the correctness of the answer I ended up having to share. I found it frustrating that *it appears* a user with some experience, in fact, more than one such user, were sharing answers and comments that were incorrect. Hopefully, a more experienced user can assist in straightening this out.

I much enjoy being able to post questions as they arise, and equally so enjoy perusing the answers given to questions already asked by others.

Comment: If you're not satisfied you can edit it as well, but you better have these overlong details in body of question.

Comment: Thank you, Mithoron. Will do.

Comment: Question titles should be like book titles. Titles distinguish a book/question  from other books/questions. They  give a hint about the content without going into details. The story/question  itself is then fully elaborated in the body. In your case, the better could be rather **"Writing linked ionic equations"**